# Is it possible to update or insert if not exist in MySQL using where-in clause without primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, where-clause

Below is my database table.

```
User
id       role        type     name
1        1           1        John
2        2           1        Doe
```

Below is my data:

```
role = 1
type = 1
name = HelloWorld

role = 1
type = 2
name = HelloWorld

rule = 3
type = 1
name = HelloWorld
```

I want the following result in my database table.

```
User
id       role        type     name
1        1           1        HelloWorld // updated name because role = 1 and type = 1 exist.
2        2           1        Doe
3        1           2        HelloWorld // inserted name because role = 1 and type = 2 do not exist.
4        3           1        Helloworld // inserted name because role = 1 and type = 2 do not exist.
```

How to write MySQL query without executing `select` query first? In my case there is no primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MySQL `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
insert into mytable (role, type, name)
values (1, 1, 'Hello World')
on duplicate key update name = values(name)
```

For this to work, you need to set up a unique key constraint on columns `(role, type)`. Create it if it doesn't yet exist:

```
alter table mytable add constraint mytable_unique_role_type unique (role, type);
```

This syntax can also be used to process multiple inserts at a time:

```
insert into mytable (role, type, name)
values (1, 1, 'Hello World'), (1, 2, 'Hello World'), (3, 1, 'Hello World')
on duplicate key update name = values(name)
```

Comment: As you can see, my sample data is a kind of array, do I have to execute the query one by one in the loop?

Comment: I did have try `insert into on duplicate key update` before asking this question, and it did not work. because the `role` and `type` column were not a unique key. And now it solvea!